# How to extract all keys / values from JSON, using Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I need to extract the "string-value" and "value" from the "contains" element in the following JSON snippet:

```
{
  "pricing-model": {
    "qualifier": {
      "and": {
        "all": {
          "equals": {
            "constant": {
              "string-value": "AFN",
              "data-type": "java.lang.String"
            },
            "value": "item.priceInfo.currencyCode"
          },
          "collection-name": "items",
          "element-name": "item"
        },
        "or": {
          "contains": [
            {
              "constant": {
                "string-value": "AF",
                "data-type": "java.lang.String"
              },
              "value": "locale.country"
            },
            {
              "constant": {
                "string-value": "IR",
                "data-type": "java.lang.String"
              },
              "value": "locale.country"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
}
```

My current approach is too simple example below only extracts one string-value, when I need to extract both:

```
with open('my.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    my_dict={}
    for item in data:
    value = item.get('pricing-model').get('qualifier').get('and').get('or')\
            .get('constant')[0].get('string-value')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unsure the keys exist, you can chain `dict.get()` with an empty `dict` as a default. That way `.get()` will always be a valid method of the result.

```
items = data.get('pricing-model', {}).get('qualifier', {}).get('and', {}).get('or', {}).get('contains', [])
values = [item.get('constant', {}).get('string-value') for item in items if item]
print(values) # ['AF', 'IR']
```

If you're certain that the keys will exist you can just access them directly as you would a standard `dict`.

```
items = data['pricing-model']['qualifier']['and']['or']['contains']
values = [item['constant']['string-value'] for item in items]
print(values)
```